# ADC on raspberry pi

Tags: rpi.gpio

I am working which with sensors on raspberry pi.I am able to connect the all digital sensors with raspbeery pi.How to start with analog sensors.Should i require a Analog to Digital converter IC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need an ADC, the Pi has no analogue inputs or outputs.

A popular choice would be an MCP300X (10 bit resolution where X is the number of channels) or MCP320X (12 bit resolution).  They connect via the Pi's SPI bus (GPIO 7-11)

You will find plenty of software and tutorials  for those chips and the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: i found a tutorial in which ADC is not used for a temperature .please through this link sensor.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2v1VNgHnvI

Comment: You need an ADC for analogue sensors.  The DS18B20 is a digital sensor.